# Block adsense ads in android webview

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I have created a website which contains ads from adsense. I have integrated the same url inside a webview of my application. As per adsense rules I can't run adsense integrated website inside an application. Please suggest a possible way to block adsense ads whenever it runs inside a webview. I will then use admob to show the ads.

Comment: pass some user-agent to your website, and according to that user-agent show or hide ads

Comment: Can you explain it in brief or share a tutorial link..

Comment: just set custom user-agent to your `WebView`. And on your frontend show or hide advertisements based on User-agent https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android+webview+custom+user+agent&*

Comment: thanks for the help.. this worked

Comment: Can you provide answer on how to set custom user agent?